# SmtpClient sends any email twice

Tags: c#, smtpclient

When I send an email using SmtpClient I found a strange behavior:

1. It took too long to be delivered.
2. It's delivered twice.

---

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
client.Port = 80;
client.Timeout = 10000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_fromAddress, _password);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Body = _body;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Subject = _subject;
message.To.Add(_toAddress);
message.Bcc.Add(_bccAddress);
message.From = new MailAddress(_fromAddress);
client.Send(message);
```

---

**Update 1:**

I'm sure that TO and BCC are different, and client.Send(message); is called only once.

---

**Update 2:**

After a lot of debugging I got the following:

- When I use my gmail as the bcc address, I receive it normally. But when I use my godaddy email as the bcc address I receive it twice.
- When my code runs locally on my development machine I receive emails without any delay. but when my code runs on azure cloud services, emails took too long to be delivered (from 5 min and up to 1 hour).

---

**Update 3:**

- When I use godaddy email in bcc address I receive it twice.

Comment: And you are not using the same address for the `TO` and `BBC` field?

Comment: Place breakpoints, go debugging. Inspect your variables.

Comment: Maybe the consuming code *invokes* this twice?  I'm pretty sure the C# `SmtpClient` object itself doesn't exhibit this behavior, somebody would have probably noticed that by now.  It's *far* more likely that the problem is either with the values you're using (same email in `to` and `bcc`?), the consuming code (invoking this twice), or the mail setup itself (one address forwarding to another?).

Comment: I've seen the .NET framework trigger methods twice. Is that happening to you when you debug?

Comment: I'm sure that TO and BCC are different, and client.Send(message); is called only once.

Comment: Don't "be sure", verify. Place breakpoints. Inspect the variables. GoDaddy's mail server "smtpout.secureserver.net" is used by thousands daily; the problem is in your code, not their servers.

Comment: I have isolated my code in a new Console Application and I have the same problems.

Answer (score 3):

The most obvious answer is that the _toAddress and _bccAddress are the same, or maybe the mailbox address where you send a BCC is redirected to the other address?

Verify under debugger that you do not run the code twice by mistake, this is also possibe.

Based on the code sample it's not possible that it sends the email twice.